# Argument not Optional - Creating a function to apply an action if a content is matched

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add the value of the column next to another, if it matches a certain content. However when I do this, I get Argument not Optional Error.

Say for example if i have the word "foo" in a cell and number 4 in the next column, I want to sum every value next to everytime i get such word, and return it in the end.

I have already tried to place optional but the function won't work anyway.I'm still trying to understand VBA so please bear with me.

Thanks in advance!

```
Function Category(word As String)
Dim i As Integer
Category = 0

For i = 0 To 100
    If Cells(i + 2, 2).Value = word Then
         Category = Category + Cells(i + 2, 3).Value
    End If

Next i

Category

End Function
```

Comment: You are calling your function at the end of your function without the `word` argument. That's one problem. You can just use Excel's `SUMIF` function instead of doing this. No VBA required.

Comment: Are you trying to make recursive function? or why are u using function name as variable?

Answer (score 1):

Per Doug's comment on the OP, you probably should not be creating a custom UDF to perform this when the built-in `SUMIF` function would be more than adequate.

However, you can remove this line:

```
Category
```

(Assuming of course, that is raising the compile error; if not, please advise)

That line, as written, is expecting an assignment such as:

```
Category = _value_
```

**OR** it is expecting the argument (`word`) of a called function, i.e.,

```
Category "something"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! SUMIF works indeed!